# Is casting a bad thing - Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have this code and I want to know if this is considered bad practice:

```
Class<T> type = null;
if (type.isInstance(TypeA.class)) {
    for (Object obj : typeAList) {
        TypeA mytype = (TypeA) obj;
        System.out.println(mytype.getMyId());
    }
}
```

typeAList is actually a parameter `List<T> typeAList`

Any bad marks here? Can this be done any better?

Comment: Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: It's wrong that it produces NPE?

Comment: NullPointerException in second line.

Comment: Is T a concrete class or bound somewhere?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Its a custom class.

Comment: @KevinRave: `type` is set to `null`, so how can you call `.isInstance()` on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `typeAList` is `List<T>` then why didn't you iterate like this:

```
for(T obj : typeAList) {
    System.out.println(obj.getMyId());
}
```

in case that `T` is defined to extend some known class/interface that have `getMyId()` method defined. Otherwise:

```
for(T obj : typeAList) {
    if (obj instanceof TypeA) {
        System.out.println(((TypeA)obj).getMyId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the 2nd one applies to my case. My question is, is it considered a bad programming / practice?

Comment: Under the hood java creates a collection of objects and uses reflection to figure out its type at run time...OVERUSE of instanceof or isInstance is generally bad practice. It means you're probably missing  a common interface somewhere.

If you're going to have a collection of objects that have similar methods but different functionality then I would use the first option suggested above. This is the true use of generics.

In the second option you're asking the JVM to figure out the type of class with each iteration. This will slow things down.